# Order of Function Calls Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)sortMyArrayAndSave {

    NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"somekeydescriptor"
                                    ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
    _myarray = [[_myarray
                        sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] mutableCopy];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_myarray
                            toFile:[self returnFilePathForType:@"myArray"]];
}
```

Can I safely assume that `_myarray` will be saved ***after*** the sort?

Comment: Yep. What makes you skeptical about this?

Comment: Why are you creating a copy of the array when sorting, and then making a mutable copy of that? If the original is mutable, just sort it...

Comment: @Wain [_myarray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] returns an NSArray....

Comment: Call `sortUsingDescriptors:` instead

Comment: @Auser I suppose the question could be: what exactly is `_myarray`? If it is mutable then just sort it, if it is not, then why are you assigning a mutable one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, methods are executed in order on the same thread, so there shouldn't be any issues.